# How to align image and iframe right of text?

Tags: html, css

How do I get an iframe to appear under an image and align to the right? Here's my code.

```
<img src="images/pc-mag.png" width="500" height="275" align="right">
<iframe width="500" height="400" align="right" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9rR5PpHSoIQ" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<h3 class="subHD">SubTitle</h3>
<p>Body paragraph</p>
```

Comment: check my jsfiddle in the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Thank you for the help. Here's the code that worked. 

<div class="FullPage">

<!--container for image and iframe -->
<div style="float:right; margin-left:20px">
<img src="images/pc-mag.png" width="500" height="275" align="right"><br>
<iframe width="500" height="400" align="right" style="margin-top:20px" src="https://www.youtube.com/" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>

<img src="../images/Logotype.png" width="190" height="101"/>
<h3>Title</h3>
<p>Body text</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    There are two image tags, not sure under which image tag you want to align iframe?

    Suggestion: You can wrap your iframe in paragraph tag and can align anywhere you want.

    For example: <p style="text-align:right;"> <!--here you can add iframe --> </p>
```

Comment: Hi Martha, I have edited my code. For some reason, it did not get posted before. you can see now

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but for some reason it displays the iframe to the left of the image and not under the image. My code is within a div tag. Should that matter?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h9jjou63/2/) i have wrapped `iframe` and `img` inside `div`s

```
iframe,img{
  float:right;
}
div{
  clear:both;
}
```